# Checking for nodes at pipe ends using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I have two features in ArcGIS Desktop 10.4; pipes and nodes. I want to check if all pipes have nodes at their end.

How can I check that?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This can be resolved with building a [topology](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Topology%20rules) and using the *end point must be covered* rule. This would identify all the polylines that break this rule.

This approach does require you to have an advance license level.